# Using sum method to get the sum of an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, sum

I am trying to get the sum of an array using sum method, but it shows up saying "incompatible types" for "return result" part at the very end. I tried to find out how I can fix it, but I'm kind of stuck.

```
public class Prog2
{

    public Prog2()
    {
        int a[] = {7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7};

        System.out.println(sum(a));

    }

    public int[] sum(int s[])
    {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i ++)
        {
            result += s [i];
        }
        return result; 
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the type of the result you are trying to return, and the type you said you would return (in the method declaration) - are they the same?

Answer (score 4):

Change `public int[] sum(int s[])`

to `public int sum(int s[])`

Since your method should return a single int, not an array.